# SQL query in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs-flux

I want to delete one row in the Followers table:

```
def unfollow
    follower = Follower.where("user_id = user_id AND followed_by = current_user_id",{user_id: params[:user_id], current_user_id: current_user.id})

    follower.destroy    
end
```

but receive this error:

```
 Started DELETE "/followers/unfollow" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-25 17:36:15 +0100
Processing by FollowersController#unfollow as */*

  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"2"}

  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):
  app/controllers/followers_controller.rb:23:in `unfollow'
```

This action is invoked by AJAX:

```
    unfollowUser(userId){
    console.log ("API.unfollowUser");   
    $.ajax({
      url: '/followers/unfollow',
      method: 'DELETE',
      data: { user_id: userId }
    }).done(unfollowUser => ServerActions.removedOneFollower(unfollowUser))
      .fail(error => console.log(error));
}
```

and it should unfollow the user who we had previously followed.

I've checked the syntax and it seems to be OK. Could someone explain how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Use find_by

```
Follower.find_by(user_id: params[:user_id]...)
```

'where' is used when you could expect to get multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

Your query return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, it's raison your destroy doesn't work. You can destroy one element.

Try this:

```
def unfollow
  follower = Follower.
    where(user_id: params[:user_id]).
    where(followed_by: current_user.id).
    take

  follower.destroy    
end
```

Or this:

```
def unfollow
  follower = Follower.find_by(
    user_id: params[:user_id],
    followed_by: current_user.id
  )
  follower.destroy
end
```

Comment: or add _all to the destroy `follower.destroy_all`  [api](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all)

Answer (score 0):

```
def unfollow
  follower = Follower.where("user_id = :user_id AND followed_by = :current_user_id", 
    user_id: params[:user_id], current_user_id: current_user.id).first

  follower.destroy    
end
```

should do it.

Active Record is actually smart enough to know that `first` should be applied before making the query (as opposed to bringing back many records and THEN taking the first one, which would be really dumb and inefficient.)